# Forward http requests to another server

Tags: server, apache2, proxy

I have several servers, but only one domain. we are behind a corporate firewall that I do not have access to, but I have a reverse proxy set up for one site.

Is it possible to set up a forward for page requests from one site to load from another server?

I am using Wordpress for my primary website hosted on the publicly accessible server eg http://www.example.com and would like requests for http://www.example.com/academy to redirect to a second server, which does not have a public IP.

I am sure this can be done, but have no idea where to start - I have googled and read hundreds of posts, but none seem to work for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mention you already have a reverse proxy set up, but the rest of the question is asking how to setup a reverse proxy. Which is it? O.o

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to the router, I do not see this happening.

first you have to think about the network, your public server sits on one side of the firewall, and has a public IP address.  then the server you want to have serve up some of the pages is on the inside of the firewall and has a non-public IP address.

Unless you can access the router/firewall and put in the rule that says requests coming to http://www.example.com/whatever are to be routed to internal address of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, then I really do not see this being able to be accomplished.

If you are able to accomplish this, then your corporate network security guys need to be fired, because there is a big hole in the firewall.

To anyone else looking at my answer, this is a corporate network, and this person has no access to the firewall or router to set rules for routing to servers on the inside.

So the final answer is to go to your network security people, or whoever controls your firewall, and ask them to create the rule to allow internet traffic to come to your server on the inside of the firewall, but you will need to make sure that server is very secure.

I hope this helps.
Chris